# Sql Query to get data from associative table

Tags: sql, relation, join

I have to fetch data from two tables
(PK) = Primary Key
(FK) = Foreign Key

```
TABLE1- [STUDENTS]
s_id(PK)     name    other
1             a        z
2             b        z
3             c        z
```

---

```
TABLE2- [CLASSES]
c_id(PK)  class_name
1           5th
2           6th
3           7th
```

---

```
TABLE3- [STUDENT-CLASS]
id(PK)    student_id(FK)     class_id(FK)
1            1                1
2            1                2

3            2                1
4            2                2

5            3                1

6            1                3
```

I want to display students with current classes(Last assigned class)
tables relations is as
when student gets admitted it is assigned class 1
after 1 year a new record is inserted in [STUDENT-CLASS] table assigning new class to each or some student
I want to display like this

```
s_id       name    other     [STUDENT-CLASS].Class_id    [CLASSES].class_nam
1         a        z                  3                        7th
2         b        z                  2                        6th
3         c        z                  1                        5th
```

Comment: yes its possible . may we know what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Select S.studentid, s.name, s.other, c.classid, c.classname
 from 
 (Select studentid, Max(Classid) as 'currentclassid' from StudentClassTable group by studentid) A
  inner join StudentTable S on A.studentid = S.Studentid 
  inner join ClassTable C on A.CurrentClassid = C.Classid
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will do the job.

```
SELECT student_id, name, other, b.last_class_id, c.class_name
FROM STUDENTS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT student_id, max(class_id) As last_class_id 
           FROM student_class
           GROUP BY student_id) b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
LEFT JOIN CLASSES c ON c.class_id = b.last_class_id
```